# C# : call REST API using certificate

Tags: c#, api, key, pem, crt

To call a REST API, the client gave me a `.crt` authority certificate, a `.pem` certificate, and a `.key` key.

Can someone tell me how to make a successful C# API call using this certificate?

A short explanation could help me to understand how to use the three files .crt, .pem, .key files.

**Note**: I had already seen questions that resemble my need but they only used the pem and key file without the crt file. At which moment should I use which one?

Comment: Afaiu, if your client is using self-signed certificate on their server, you must add it to your trusted certificates list to connect to it using https. Then you can make api calls as usual. See example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate or google the process for you system.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried successfully to call the API using curl command: curl -X GET -v "HTTPS: //urlwithparameters" --proxy address: port --concert "authority_cert. CRT" --key "my. key" --cert "certification. Pem" but I can not translate it in C#